# Dynamic table name in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I need to select columns from a table Table_A, However there is another table which has the same schema Table_B. The query should determine the from table dynamically. For ex. if Table_A  has more rows then use Table_A else use Table_B.

Query something like this
 select employee, salary, id from (*condition to count rows and select the table* )table;

Is this possible without using cursors and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE??.

Comment: No, it's not possible without either dbms_sql, execute immediate or cursors in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would use dynamic SQL for this sort of thing.  That would involve either using the `DBMS_SQL` package, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or doing an `OPEN <<cursor>> FOR <<SQL statement string>>`.

If you really want to use static SQL, you could query both tables and only return one set of results.  I cannot envision a situation where this would really make sense but you can certainly do it

Create a `FOO` and a `FOO2` table.  `FOO2` has two rows to the one row from `FOO`

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> create table foo2( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo2 values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo2 values( 2 );

1 row created.
```

Run the query.  This will return all the data from `FOO2`

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select col1
  2    from (select the_union.*,
  3                 max(cnt) over () max_cnt
  4            from (select col1, count(*) over () cnt from foo
  5                  union all
  6                  select col1, count(*) over () from foo2) the_union)
  7*  where cnt = max_cnt
SQL> /

      COL1
----------
         1
         2
```

Insert more rows into `FOO`.  Now the same query will return all the data from `FOO`

```
SQL> insert into foo values( 3 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 5 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select col1
  2    from (select the_union.*,
  3                 max(cnt) over () max_cnt
  4            from (select col1, count(*) over () cnt from foo
  5                  union all
  6                  select col1, count(*) over () from foo2) the_union)
  7   where cnt = max_cnt;

      COL1
----------
         1
         3
         5
```

As I said, though, I cannot fathom a situation where it would actually make sense to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the query. I'm using this query in a inline view which is a part of big select statement creating a view. Any suggestions to do it dynamically to create a view is highly appreciated.

Comment: @user1876832 - I'm not sure that I understand the question. You can use the approach I outlined above in a view. If you don't want to hit both tables every time you run the query, you'd need to use dynamic SQL (`DBMS_SQL`, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `OPEN cursor FOR query`).  If you are talking about a DDL statement (`CREATE VIEW`), though, dynamic SQL makes even less sense-- since you should only be issuing DDL at install time, it seems highly unusual that you would want your view to hit different tables depending on the state of the data when the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely guessing at what you are really trying to do, but I am thinking you want to use a synonym.  I am guessing that there is some sort of event that triggers when you should be using TableA vs. TableB.  Create a synonym "my_table" pointing to TableA and have your view select from "my_table".  Then whenever you want your view to point to TableB instead, you just switch your synonym to point to TableB, and you don't have to do anything to the view.

For more info, [read about synonyms in the Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CNCPT711).

Comment: You can't switch synonym's in PL/SQL without using dbms_sql, execute immediate or constructed cursors so there's little point in this suggestion as the OP will still have to do the same thing.

Comment: @Ben - I understand that, but am still guessing this is really what OP is wanting to do.  I think the requirement listing is wrong, that OP just put that because they want to put the table reference in a view, and not saying they can't use execute immediate at any point in the process.  But again, this is all just guesses from the vague problem description.